# String Manipulation in Java

Tags: java, string

```
String xpath = "//center/div";
```

I would like to manipulate the above string so that my resulting output inside the `for loop` is:

```
String new_xpath = "//center"
String var_xpath = "/div"

for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
String temp = //center/div[i]
```

I know I have to do something like:

```
String temp = new_xpah + var_xpath + [i]
```

I need the above structure so that I can loop inside all my 'div elements' to fetch data.

Comment: Why are you iterating to 5? You question seems a bit unclear to me.

Comment: @RanRag, you might want to count the number of `div`s before you iterate them, otherwise you risk an aioobe.

Comment: Qwerky: He's not accessing those elements, he just wants to generate the strings I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
String temp = new_xpah + var_xpath + "[" + i + "]";
```

Answer (score 6):

[StringBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) should be used for the concatenation since it's faster and consumes less memory.

```
public class Lala {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String xpath = "//center/div";

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append(xpath);
            builder.append('[');
            builder.append(i);
            builder.append(']');

            System.out.println( builder.toString() );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, `StringBuilder` is not needed here. The Java compiler would automatically transform `xpath+"["+i+"]"` to use a `StringBuilder`. The string concatenation version also has the advantage of being easier to read.

Comment: Do you have a citation that this optimisation is performed?

Comment: @Rakesh: Where does it say under that link that the optimisation is performed?

Comment: @MikeKwan In that page, under the sub heading **`b) Short messages and the like`** it says the compiler transforms the String concatenation using `+` to `StringBuilder.append()`